# Access restriction: The type 'Response' is not API (restriction on required library /javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar

Tags: java, rest, mule, mule-studio

I am learning MULE and I was using REST Component for Practice in my class.

I get following error.

[image]

Why am I getting this error?
How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Go to the Build Path settings in the project properties.
2. Remove the JRE System Library Add it back;
3. Select "Add Library" and select the JRE System Library. The default worked for me.

   Removing and re-adding the JRE lib will make the right classes be first. If you want a
   fundamental solution make sure you exclude the jar files with the same classes.